# python batch change csv date

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to batch change the date column values in csv files while also removing the leading part of the string. The current format is, for example "Company Name Here Oct  2 2016  9:43PM". I need the date in ISO format, like this "20161021502".

I'm stuck on splitting the object from the csv file, getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File   "C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\dealerTestData.py", line 13, in <module>
month, day, year, time = newDate.split()
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

So far my code looks like this:

```
dealerFile =  open('C:/Users/dave/Downloads/Prospect_Source_Measurement_Details-    2016112.csv')
dealerReader = csv.reader(dealerFile)
dealerData = list(dealerReader)
dealerData


for index in dealerData:
    newDate = (index[0])[-19:]
    totalDate = repr(newDate)

    month, day, year, time = newDate.split()

    time = datetime.strptime(time, '%I:%M%p')
    month = datetime.strptime(month, '%b')
    totalDate = year + month.strftime('%m') + day + time.strftime('%H%M')
    print(newDate)
```

If I comment out the everything past `newDate = index[0][-19:]` can print out the entire column minus the Company Name. As soon as I try to represent it as a string and parse it, I get the error.

Comment: print `newDate` and see what you get. It seems it has only two elements but you try to assign to four variables.

Comment: Actually `20161021502` is not exactly a valid ISO 8601 date. You are missing `T` delimiter:  `2016102T1502`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. When reading the file, there are 5 heading lines that parse differently than the body of the file. Once they are removed the logic is sound.